# Drupal - 7: Display Flag link only for Node Author

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I`m trying to Display Flag link only for Node Author,

I`m using this code:

`global $user;

if ($node->uid == $user->uid) {

  //print your flag

}`

But the link don`t appear.

Any ideas what is causing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code should read like this:

`<?php global $user; if ($node->uid == $user->uid): ?>
// print your flag code here <?php endif; ?>`